# How to remove words with # or $ at the end of a sentence to be removed (Regex)

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following:

```
The moment #BTC, we have all $BTC been waiting for:We are happy to announce NIX Platform is rebranding to.. $NBT > $VOICE $NIX > $MUTE $ETH $BTC #BTC
```

I would like to remove only the remove the words with # or $ to be removed from the end, not the middle, so the above string would look like this

```
The moment #BTC, we have all $BTC been waiting for:We are happy to announce NIX Platform is rebranding to..  >  >
```

Currently I have `#(?!(?:hashtag)\b)[\w-]+(?=(?:\s+#[\w-]+)*\s*$)` as regex that removes words with # from end but not $, not sure what I need to include those as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative regex with a word boundary and negative lookahead to disallow any word character following a whitespace:

```sh
[#$@]\w+\b(?!\W*\s\w)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YXLJXs/1)

**RegEx Explanation:**

- `[#$@]`: Match `#` or `$` or `@`
- `\w+b`: Match 1+ word characters followed by word boundary
- `(?!\W*\s\w)`: Negative lookahead to assert that we don't have a word character after a whitespace ahead of current position

*Alternatively*, you can also use an *atomic group` to disallow backtracking:

```
[#$@](?>\w+)(?!\W*\s\w)
```

Comment: I like it :-) You are the master, I am the apprentice

Comment: @anubhava .net doesnt support possessive qualifiers, is there a better way? also how would I add another item, want it to remove words with #, $ and @

Comment: @Zoinky: Please try: `[#@$]\w+\b(?!\W*\s\w)`

Answer (score 3):

You could use a positive lookahead and assert that until the end of the string all words start with a non word character.

```
[#$][^\s$#]+(?=(?:\s+[^\w\s]\S*)*\s*$)
```

- `[#$][^\s$#]+` Match either `#` or `$` and 1+ occurrences of any char except `#` or `$`
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert on the right

  - `(?:\s+[^\w\s]\S*)*` Optional repetitions of 1 or more whitespace chars followed by any char except a whitspace or char char
  - `\s*` Match optional trailing whitspace chars
  - `$` End of string
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LAuK1h/1)

---

If the start with `$` or `#` can contain the other one, another option could be using a tempered greedy token approach with a capture group and a backreference `\1`.

To prevent partial matches, you might add asserting a whitespace boundary at the left.

```
(?<!\S)([#$])(?:(?!\1)\S)*(?=(?:\s+[^\w\s]\S*)*\s*$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vl7ykx/1)

Comment: @anubhava Certainly it would, I have changed it into a positive lookahead. You could post your pattern :-)

Comment: Positive lookahead is even better ++